# Maven: where is the proper place to set internal repo site

Tags: java, maven, repository, pom.xml

it seems to me there are 2 places where I might want to set the internal maven repo:

1. In maven's settings.xml inside the mirror tag;
2. In the project's pom file, inside repository and pluginRepository tags.

The question is, which one is right? or shall I put the internal repo in both places?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

In both :-(

You [add the repo definition](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers) (server ID, URL and **login credentials**) to Maven's settings.xml and [add a reference to that repo](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories) (by ID) inside your project's pom.xml. It's cumbersome, but it lets your credentials stay away from shared files.

Maven docs state:

> The repositories for download and deployment are defined by the
>   **repositories** and **distributionManagement** elements of the POM. However,
>   certain settings such as username and password should not be
>   distributed along with the pom.xml. This type of information should
>   exist on the build server in the settings.xml.

Comment: thanks, Kaqqao. according to you, in my settings.xml, I need to fill up name, id and url inside mirror tag, and again in the pom, i filled up name, id and url inside repository tag? it indeed cumbersome and error prone. If my settings.xml doesn't include authentication, can i skip the part in settings.xml?

Comment: As far as I know, yes, you should be able to skip the settings.xml part if you so desire. Updated the answer a little.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend putting repository definitions in your pom.  I have been bitten many times by a pom in my dependency list including repository definitions to repositories that I can't reach.

By putting these in settings.xml, you allow each developer the freedom to control which repositories are used when running a build.  Since developers sometimes work disconnected or across a VPN, it can be desirable for this list of repositories to be different from machine to machine.

Remember also that the POM becomes immutable once a release is performed, effectively making the repository URL you defined permanent.  Placing it in settings.xml allows your future team members the freedom to move the repository (or remove it).